# Mudar fundo a um elemento através de jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu gostaria de fazer algo como esta representado na imagem a baixo ou seja queria mudar o fundo do `<a href>` quando é clicado noutro `<a href>` em baixo.

Isto não acontece 1 vez só, pode acontecer varias vezes e eu nunca sei em que elemento estou a clicar porque eles tem a mesma `class`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poste por favor o código que já tem tentado em vez de imagem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes fazer assim com jQuery:

```
$('li > a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.style.backgroundColor = '#fdf';
});
```

Assim cada vez que um elemento `a` descendente direto de um `li` fôr clicado acontecem duas coisas:

- o evento `click` é cancelado para evitar mudar de página (também podes evitar isto com `href="#"`
- o elemento clicado (o `this` dentro dessa callback) recebe uma nova côr de fundo.

Exemplo:

```js
$('li > a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.style.backgroundColor = '#fdf';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>texto</li>
    <li>texto</li>
    <li><a href>Link</a>
        <ul>
            <li>texto</li>
            <li>texto</li>
            <li><a href>Link</a>
                <ul></ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){                        // Espera para executar ate o dom ter sido renderizado
  $('.change_color').on('click', 'li', function(){   // Cria um evento de click para os li do elemento ul
    var color = this.getAttribute('data-value');     // recupera a cor que esta no data-value
    $('.content').css({background:color});           // aplica a cor no elemento do class content
  })
})
```

```css
.content{
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background:yellow;
}

.change_color li {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
</div>

<ul class="change_color">
  <li data-value="red">red</li>
  <li data-value="green">green</li>
  <li data-value="blue">blue</li>
  <li data-value="#CCC">gray</li>
</ul>
```